# Fourier transformation formula confusion

Tags: fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

I found two formulas for Fourier transformation , which one is correct.

1. $$ F[f(x)]=\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{ipx} dx $$
2. $$ F[f(x)]= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{ipx} dx $$

Or if both are correct where to use which formula?

Comment: To the first one corresponds an inverse fourier transform with a $\frac{1}{\sqrt(2*\pi)}$ factor; the second one a $\frac{1}{2*\pi}$ factor

Comment: follow this: [Units and duality of Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Units_and_duality)

Answer (score 2):

The two formula only differ by a constant factor, which is really unessential. Other conventions exist, with an exponent $i2\pi px$ rather than $ipx$, and the choice is mainly a matter of taste and convenience.

In addition, many problems are solved by taking direct transforms followed by inversion, and the constant factor just vanishes. So you shouldn't worry much: the first computation you will write will make it clear which definition you use. And you are always free to state it explicitly.

Comment: means i can use any formula to find transformation in exam

Comment: @AbhishecKumar: you'd better use the definition your teacher gave.

Comment: my teacher give 2nd formula, but the book i am using uses 1st formula,,

Comment: @AbhishecKumar: use the teacher's book ;-)